# Exploits on public read-access S3 bucket

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am debating whether to use S3 as a CDN storage. The first step is to allow the bucket to have read-access to everyone, which I did with the policy and is working fine. I am expecting the bucket to contain media files: jpg, png, gif, mp4.

Now, I am only allowing WRITE access to the Django server which is writing to S3 using [django-storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Thus the question is:

**What are the possible explots with this setup?**

I stumbled upon this [blog](http://cloudcheckr.com/2012/05/write-permissions-granted-to-everyone-on-a-bucket/) which mentions that READ access to the public is discouraged thus made me wonder what the community thinks.

Comment: Just a note that S3 really isn't a CDN, just file storage. If you care about performance and security I would put a CDN like CloudFront or CloudFlare or MaxCDN in front of it.

Comment: I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the blog suggests not having public Read access is that a malicious user can `list` all objects in your bucket. I think this is a valid security concern: on a bucket with public Read access, I should be able to get content for a given S3 key, but shouldn't be allowed to view what all objects it contains.

This blog was written in 2012. I don't know whether S3 had support for bucket policies back then. Today, you can easily deal with this situation by defining a bucket policy to `Allow` ALL to `GetObject`, but `Deny` ALL to `ListObjects`.

On a side note, have you considered using AWS CloudFront to work as a CDN? That seems to be a better fit for your use case, rather then S3.